# How to display object in a variable in Vue 3 script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I can't display object in Vue 3 script setup. I used ref, reactive and standard variables but all scenarios is unsuccessful.

I want to reflect the response from the getDetail request to the screen. getDetail is fetching this data asynchronously. I run into a problem in every scenario.

### ref() usage

```
<script setup>
let movie = ref([])

const getMovieData = async ()=> {

try {
const data =  await getDetail('movie', route.params.id)
movie.value.push(data)
}
catch (e){
console.log(e)
}

}
getMovieData()
</script>
<template>

<h1>{{movie[0].original_title}}</h1>

</template>
```

I am able to show data in this usage but I am getting these errors
[image: ref() Error]

---

### reactive() usage

```
<script setup>
let movie = reactive({
  data:null
})

const getMovieData = async ()=>{
  try {
    const data =  await getDetail('movie', route.params.id)
    movie.data = data
  }catch (e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
getMovieData()
</script>

<template>
<h1>{{movie.data.original_title}}</h1>
</template>
```

In this usage I can show data but I get similar errors
[image: reactive()errors]

---

### Standart variable usage

```
<script setup>

let movie

const getMovieData = async ()=>{
  try {
    const data =  await getDetail('movie', route.params.id)
    movie =data
  }catch (e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
getMovieData()
</script>

<template>
<h1>{{movie.id}}</h1>
</template>
```

In this usage, the data does not appear on the screen, because the movie object is formed asynchronously.

---

How do I manage to display this object on the screen in the most correct way without getting an error?

Comment: You might take a look at `suspense`. https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template code runs immediately on component creation.  In each case, before movie has been asynchronously assigned, your template code is trying to access some non-existent property.  [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is arguably the easiest way to prevent these types of errors:

```js
movie[0]?.original_title
```

Another option is to provide a default value that matches your template usage so it doesn't error out:

```js
let movie = ref([
  {
    original_title: ''
  }
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a v-if `<h1 v-if="movie && movie.length">{{movie[0].id}</h1>` So it only renders when data is available.

Comment: This is also the solution, but I can only make one choice :(